# jquery tooltip, tooltips appearing too far

Tags: tooltip

I've a list of names here, and using jquery's tooltip to show profile photo on hover. However, when I hover, the images are appearing too far, and left aligned to the screen.

Can anyone give me an idea ?

http://reveillon.formationweb.net/after.php

I have tried to make a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyCh/ZZzG7/ but here the images are not even visible, the above link after.php, images are seen to the left.

```
<ul id="quiviennent">
            <li><a id="sabah" title="">Sabah</a></li>
            <li><a id="elicia" title="">Elicia</a></li>
            <li><a id="celine" title="">Celine</a></li>
            <li><a id="audrey" title="">Audrey</a></li>
            <li><a id="bruno" title="">Bruno</a></li>
            <li><a id="saidou" title="">Saidou</a></li>
        </ul>

$( "#sabah" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/sabah.jpg" />' });
    $( "#elicia" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/elicia.jpg" />' });
    $( "#celine" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/celine.jpg" />' });
    $( "#saidou" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/saidou.jpg" />' });
    $( "#bruno" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/noimg.jpg" />' });
    $( "#audrey" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/noimg.jpg" />' });

#quiviennent li a { cursor: pointer; }
```

Thanks
Jeremy

Comment: Give us some code... maybe a fiddle ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `position` option? http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [position option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) to specify where you want the tooltip to appear in relation to the element it's attached to.

For example

```
$( "#sabah" ).tooltip({ 
      content: '<img src="http://reveillon.formationweb.net/images/sabah.jpg" />',
      position :  { my: "left+100 center", at: "left center" }
});
```

puts the photo slightly to the right of the list.

Comment: not working, the cursor is also jumping now I observed. See the link : http://reveillon.formationweb.net/after.php

Comment: It worked for me, but nevermind. You seem to have found another solution, but have you considered using pure CSS? For example http://jsfiddle.net/ZZzG7/2/ (image position relative to `a`) or http://jsfiddle.net/ZZzG7/3/ (image position relative to `ul`)